# why not ironclad:decrypt-in-place work as expected?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ironclad

the code as follow:

```
(ql:quickload :ironclad)
(ql:quickload :crypto-shortcuts)

(use-package :ironclad)

(defparameter str "Hello World!")
(defparameter message (ascii-string-to-byte-array str))
(defparameter key "1234")

(let ((cipher (make-cipher :arcfour
                           :key (ascii-string-to-byte-array key)
                           :mode :stream
                           :initialization-vector (make-random-salt)))
      (text
       (ascii-string-to-byte-array
        (cryptos:to-base64 (copy-seq message)))))
  ;; #(83 71 86 115 98 71 56 103 86 50 57 121 98 71 81 104)
  (format t "~a~%" text)
  (encrypt-in-place cipher text)
  ;; #(86 14 39 220 145 171 63 106 89 41 57 41 135 32 85 188)
  ;; "Vg4n3JGrP2pZKTkphyBVvA=="
  (format t "~a~%" text)
  (format t "~a~%" (cryptos:to-base64 text))
  (decrypt-in-place cipher text)
  ;; ?
  ;; #(83 71 86 115 98 71 56 103 86 50 57 121 98 71 81 104)
  (format t "~a~%" text))
```

what's wrong with my code?

after `(decrypt-in-place cipher text)`, `text` should be same as the original, but it doesn't. why?

can anyone help?

below is the crypto-shortcuts version:

```
(cryptos:decrypt (cryptos:encrypt str
                              key                                  
                              :cipher :arcfour
                              :mode :stream)
             key
             :cipher :arcfour
             :mode :stream)
```

everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, the algorithm of the cipher `arcfour` in `Ironclad` is cumulative: at each step of the algorithm, the internal result is changing.

Here, you reuse the result of the `encryption` into the `decryption`. At that very moment, the internal state of the cipher is *not* initialized properly, its value is the result of the previous encryption.

In order to work properly, the `decryption` cipher need to be initialized in the same way as the `encryption` cipher.

The most easy way is to create 2 instances of `cipher`:

```
(let* ((salt (make-random-salt))
       (cipher-encrypt (make-cipher :arcfour
                                    :key (ascii-string-to-byte-array key)
                                    :mode :stream
                                    :initialization-vector salt))
       (cipher-decrypt (make-cipher :arcfour
                                    :key (ascii-string-to-byte-array key)
                                    :mode :stream
                                    :initialization-vector salt))
       (text
        (ascii-string-to-byte-array
         (cryptos:to-base64 (copy-seq message)))))
  ;; #(83 71 86 115 98 71 56 103 86 50 57 121 98 71 81 104)
  (format t "~a~%" text)
  (encrypt-in-place cipher-encrypt text)
  ;; #(86 14 39 220 145 171 63 106 89 41 57 41 135 32 85 188)
  ;; "Vg4n3JGrP2pZKTkphyBVvA=="
  (format t "~a~%" text)
  (format t "~a~%" (cryptos:to-base64 text))
  (decrypt-in-place cipher-decrypt text)
  ;; ?
  ;; #(83 71 86 115 98 71 56 103 86 50 57 121 98 71 81 104)
  (format t "~a~%" text))
#(83 71 86 115 98 71 56 103 86 50 57 121 98 71 81 104)
#(86 14 39 220 145 171 63 106 89 41 57 41 135 32 85 188)
Vg4n3JGrP2pZKTkphyBVvA==
#(83 71 86 115 98 71 56 103 86 50 57 121 98 71 81 104)
```

Comment: you are right, it's the answer. thanks.